# How to update dataframe values based on conditions?

Tags: r, xlsx, rodbc

I am needing to see how I can update dataframe values in R based on a condition and then use a query to SQL Server to make the calculations and replace that value within the dataframe.

Right now for example, my dataframe looks like this:

```
empID     name     description     annl_salary
123       John     driver          0
789       Smith    temp            0
246       Joe      manager         60000
```

So basically for example, any user that is "temp", the annl_salary column for them will always show 0, but for the "driver" description sometimes there will be 0 for this description and so I am needing to see if there is a way to:

1. Check to see if there are any 0 values in the annl_salary column where the description IS NOT equal to "temp"
2. If there are any, then run a SQL Query to calculate the salary and update the 0 value in the dataframe for each specific user that has a 0 salary and is not a temp
3. Then sort the dataframe by annl_salary and description in ascending order and export to xlsx file

I am still new to R and so far I have this but I am stuck:

```
library(RODBC)
library(xlsx)

data <- read.xlsx("Book1.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet1")

if(data$annl_salary == 0 & data$description != "temp"){data$annl_salary = "SQL Query from RODBC to update the values for each user with 0 and not driver"}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a `sql` solution or `R`

Comment: I am looking for R solution

Comment: Just do `with(data, annl_salary == 0 & description != 'temp')`

Comment: Ok I see, if I use that though how will I incorporate the part where if any row meets that condition, then to run a SQL statement within R using RODBC to update those fields?

Comment: Your terminology is confusing. The *data frame* is in R. Updating the data frame is done all within R. You also have a data source, which might be Excel file or might be a SQL Server database--this isn't clear in your question. Your code shows an Excel file source, but your text talks about SQL Server. If you want to update a table in a SQL database, your best off just using SQL code, not R code. (Though you can run the SQL command from within R, if you want to.) If all you need is an Excel file, then an easier workflow might skip SQL. But it seems like your mixing technologies for no reason.

Comment: Which is to say, if all you *really* want to do is update a table in a SQL database and get an Excel export of it, I'm not sure why you'd use R to run the SQL commands. It would make sense if you were already super-comfortable with R and RODBC, and that was just an easy way to do it, but that's not the case here.

Comment: I agree with @Gregor. You should be able to do it directly and that would be faster/efficient.  The update thing in databases have to do a lot behind the hood

Comment: Sorry if I made this a bit confusing, I'm not actually trying to update the actual SQL Server table, only the spreadsheet. Basically I extract the data from SQL Server and put it into a spreadsheet, then from there, the reason I am needing to reference RODBC and SQL Server is because I need to update that spreadsheet only, fixing the 0 values by making the calculations through SQL Server, but I am not updating any actual tables, only just the data in the xlsx file.

Comment: You talk about an SQL query to calculate the salary, how is this supposed to happen?

Comment: It's still confusing why you're mentioning SQL Server at all. It seems like your goal is to update a spreadsheet. Do you have or can you get the values you want in R? If yes, then we don't care where they come from or how you got them, and we can focus on getting the values from R to the spreadsheet, which *may* involve RODBC but probably will not involve SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this but it's hard to know without understanding the structure of the SQL database you need to query.

```
library(RODBC)

channel <- odbcConnect("database")
sqlQuery(channel, paste("SQL QUERY"))

data$annl_salary <- ifelse(data$description != 'Temp' & data$annl_salary == 0, query, data$annl_salary)

data <- data %>%
    arrange(annl_salary)
```